# How to start my telegram bot on Google Cloud

Tags: python, telegram, daemon, python-daemon

I want to upload my bot to the server. I am using Google Cloud. My `bot.service` file looks like this:

```
[Unit]
Description=Telegram bot 'ConverterBot'
After=syslog.target
After=network.target

[Service]
Type=simple
User=root
WorkingDirectory=/home/misha_markov1015@converterbot/ConverterBot
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python3 /home/misha_markov1015@converterbot/ConverterBot/main.py

RestartSec=10
Restart=always

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

When I enter the following commands:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo systemctl enable bot
sudo systemctl start bot
sudo systemctl status bot
```

I get the following error:

```
Nov 01 19:08:53 converterbot systemd[1]: Started Telegram bot 'ConverterBot'.
Nov 01 19:08:53 converterbot systemd[8978]: bot.service: Changing to the requested working directory failed: No such file or directory
Nov 01 19:08:53 converterbot systemd[8978]: bot.service: Failed at step CHDIR spawning /usr/bin/python3: No such file or directory
Nov 01 19:08:53 converterbot systemd[1]: bot.service: Main process exited, code=exited, status=200/CHDIR
Nov 01 19:08:53 converterbot systemd[1]: bot.service: Failed with result 'exit-code'.
```

If you start the bot with the `/home/python3/ConverterBot/main.py` command, then everything works correctly. I checked several times: the path to this file exists, but why does the error say that this file does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

If suddenly someone encounters such a problem, then the solution was as follows: `/home/misha_markov1015@converterbot/ConverterBot` this path really does not exist. Instead, you had to write: `/home/misha_markov1015/ConverterBot`.